# ViewPager: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, image, exception

I have an app where i use ViewPager and set in every page"Fragment" an image.

when i scroll the view pager after image 25 it is giving me out of memory exception but i delete the image every time go to next page.

check code below:

```
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    Log.d("**", "remove image");
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ImageView) view);
} //method: remove item from pager adapter
```

i tried code from here to delete ImageView but it did not solved the problem:

```
  private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
     if (view.getBackground() != null) {
          view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
     }
     if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
           unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
      }
}
```

*edit:*
below code will solve the problem, but i want to use the full image size and why it is not delete the image?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2; //reduce image size
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues:

1. Your images are just too big
2. The  GC might not be running as quickly as it has to. If you're using bitmaps you should call `recycle()` after your remove them from the views. This makes sure the GC can reclaim the memory. Be careful if these Bitmaps are reused in any of the other views though.